# Display Contact Type

Tags: java

I have written a program that allows me to enter business or personal contacts and then be able to view them.  I have used subclasses for the different types of contacts.  When I view the contacts I would like be able to see if they are business or personal but haven't been able to find the right way to do it.  I have included a piece of the code showing how I am inputting them and what I am calling to view them.

```
public static void addContact(ArrayList<Contact> ContactRecords) {
    Scanner textIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("First Name: ");
    String firstName = textIn.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Last Name: ");
    String lastName = textIn.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Address:  ");
    String address = textIn.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Email Address: ");
    String email = textIn.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Phone: ");
    String phone = textIn.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Is this a 1) Personal or 2) Business?");
    int choice = keyIn.nextInt();
    if (choice == 1) {
        System.out.println("Date of Birth:  ");
        String dateOfBirth = textIn.nextLine();
        Personal aPersonal = new Personal(firstName, lastName, address, 
        email, phone, dateOfBirth);
        ContactRecords.add(aPersonal);
    }
    if (choice == 2) {
        System.out.println("Job Title:  ");
        String jobTitle = textIn.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Organization: ");
        String organization = textIn.nextLine();
        Business aBusiness = new Business(firstName, lastName, address, 
        email, phone, jobTitle, organization);
        ContactRecords.add(aBusiness);
    }

}

public static void getRecords(ArrayList<Contact> ContactRecords)
{
    Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Contacts who have been entered:");
    for (int i = 0; i < ContactRecords.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(i + ") "+ ContactRecords.get(i).getFirstName() + 
        " " + ContactRecords.get(i).getLastName());
    }
    System.out.println("Please enter the number corresponding to the contact
    you would like to view: ");
    int choice = keyIn.nextInt();

    System.out.println(ContactRecords.get(choice).toString());
}

}
```

So right now when I view a contact that I have added what I am seeing is First Name, Last Name, Address, Email, Phone then depending on the type of contact either Date of Birth (for Personal) or Job Title and Organization (for Business).  I would also like to see either Business or Personal in my when it returns my contact info but just not sure.  I tried adding to my system.out.println ContactRecords.get(choice).get(Class) but that returns it as class contactlist.personal.  I just want to return Personal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
getClass().getSimpleName()
```

on the contact entry. But I'd recommend adding a method to Contact getType() to return either a static String on the class

```
public class Business extends Contact {
    private static final String TYPE = "Business";
    ...
    @Override // method on Contact
    public String getType() {
        return TYPE
    }
```

Or return an Enum

```
public enum ContactType {
    Personal, Bussiness
}

public class Business extends Contact {
    private static final ContactType TYPE = ContactType.Business;
    ...
    @Override // method on Contact
    public ContactType getType() {
        return TYPE
    }
```